# Eliminar zona gris en imágenes

Tags: css, ionic, imagen

Estoy insertando imágenes en un html. El problema es que me encuentro que me sale una zona gris en las fotos que son más pequeñitas y me gustaría que desapareciera.

Actualmente este es el CSS que tengo.

```
<ion-img max-width="100%" height="150" src="{{element.image}}"></ion-img>
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando tienes imágenes con distintas resoluciones lo mejor es forzar el ancho o el alto al 100% y fijar el otro valor a un tamaño fijo, aunque también puedes forzarlo al 100% y hacer uso de la propiedad `object-fit` para adaptar la imagen sacrificando los márgenes de esta.

con tu código podrías hacer algo así:

html:

```
<ion-img src="{{element.image}}"></ion-img>
```

css / scss:

```
ion-img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Aunque también podrías poner el width y height al 100% y el object-fit se encargaría de estirar tu imagen para que todas tengan el mismo tamaño. Como dato extra también existe una propiedad  `object-position` que te permite elegir qué parte de tu imagen quieres que se centre. Sus valores pueden variar entre center, bottom... Puedes ver más información acerca de `object-fit` y `object-position` en [este enlace](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte. La verdad no entiendo la cantidad de negativos a la pregunta. Para que lo entienda html, se debe declarar como: `ion-img img {}`. Gracias!

Comment: Cierto, ionic genera dentro del elemento ion-img una imagen. También se puede crear con una clase de css en lugar de con la referencia a la etiqueta